# Advice on refactoring Business/Data Logic in preparation for migrating WebForms to MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns, refactoring

I'm looking some advice on to a strategy for migrating from Asp.Net WebForms to MVC. I currently have a solution of approx 60 projects in the following format:

Solution

- ProjectA.DataModel
- ProjectA.Business
- ProjectA.Web
- ProjectB.DataModel
- ProjectB.Business
- ProjectB.Web
- Framework.Core
- Framework.Common
  …etc

All data models are Entity Framework 6 using database first (.edmx) and T4 templates. Data access code is mixed between both the Business and Web (WebForms) projects. The code base has grown organically initially from a sole developer through to a small team which explains some of the bad practice in terms of SOC however we want to try take this opportunity to rectify this.

I want to start moving towards a full MVC solution and feel the first thing to do is ensure any data access logic currently residing in the Web projects is pushed to the Business layer to get Separation of Concerns. Researching into a best practice for this has taken me towards the Unit of Work and Repository patterns however further reading seems to be suggesting this is overkill.

What would be the best approach to refactoring my Business and Data Layers with the current Web Forms model in readiness for MVC. Secondly is an accepted approach for migration to MVC to bring in Views to the existing WebForms solution to create a Hybrid or to create a new MVC project, reference my existing BAL and DAL and start building the application UI from scratch?

In regards to Entity Framework, everything appears to be moving towards a CodeFirst approach. Is this something we need to be planning for if we want to go forward with a best practice approach?

We are currently a very small team and want to try make best possible re-use of our existing projects and refactor as much as possible to get into a position of beginning to move towards MVC.

Any thoughts on how I can begin to approach this is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: May interest you: http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html

Comment: thanks Mik378 I will take a read through that link

Comment: > everything appears to be moving towards a CodeFirst approach.... Yeah, big time. For the last couple years. Code First is the way forward.

Comment: Btw code first is JUST the way the db is created, is still a persistence detail and has nothing to do with Domain/Business first. So code first is [database design](http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2014/01/13/Do-Either-DDD-or-DDD-But-Not-DDD.aspx) first but we use code instead of vs designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nasty app you have there. Anywas, first thing to rembmer is that MVC is a UI pattern. So in a properly designed app the swtich from WebForms to Mvc would mean just change the UI layer.

> I want to start moving towards a full MVC solution and feel the first thing to do is ensure any data access logic currently residing in the Web projects is pushed to the Business layer to get Separation of Concerns

No! Data access logic should be in the DAL (hint: it's an acronym), not BL, not UI. Persistence Only. BL and UI would ask the DAL to save/retrieve their **objects** via Repository. And btw, EF deals with db only. Don't make the mistake to build your business objects on top of Ef Entities. One models business concept and behaviour, the other model database access. They're usually not compatible. When dealing with anything but persistence, ignore that you have a db or an ORM.

> Researching into a best practice for this has taken me towards the Unit of Work and Repository patterns however further reading seems to be suggesting this is overkill.

It's overkill ONLY if you a have a very simple app that you don't care about maintaining it. I know is hard to believe but probably over 80%(more or less random number) of devs still don't understand how to properly implement the Repository pattern that's why it becomes useless for them. In a nutshell, the repo *uses* the EF but it's not built on top of it. The repo 'transforms' business/ui objects to EF entities and vice versa.

The repo interface should **never** expose IQueryable or the fact that you're using a db in the first place. So, no generic repositories and no exposing of EF entities. Also, the Bl/UI shouldn't create queries (it would mean they know how the data is stored - a DAL implementation detail), that's the repository's job. THe higher layers just tell the repository *what* they want, never *how* to do it.

> Secondly is an accepted approach for migration to MVC to bring in Views to the existing WebForms solution to create a Hybrid or to create a new MVC project, reference my existing BAL and DAL and start building the application UI from scratch?

Although you can mix WebForms and Mvc in the same project, it's better not to do it (less headaches). Start the mvc app from scratch then port the web forms pages to it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. We are going to take a look at using  Repositories and UOW and follow some of the best practices you have mentioned above. It may take as longer to get there but we may as well take the opportunity to do it right. We are also going to migrate the webforms by creating a fresh MVC site and go that way too.

Comment: @belfastdev I'm in a similar situation. how are you progressing? Any good references I can read?